# Increase maximum size of POST or PUT request to Kentico REST services over 64KB

Tags: asp.net, rest, kentico

Using Kentico 10, we're having issues raising the maximum request limit size above the default 64KB limit for any requests that go to the [servername]/rest/ services. All POST or PUT requests over that limit are met with server error 413 - request entity too large. In other parts of the application (such as the Kentico Admin) this limit does not exist as we're able to send POST and PUT requests with much higher amounts of data.

We've tried adding the following configuration to our web.config file but this does not affect the 64KB limit:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097151" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

In addition, we've added a location element to the web.config with the following settings:

```
<location path="rest">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="2400" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2000000000" maxRequestEntityAllowed="32000000" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" />
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Neither of the configuration changes above had any affect on the POST or PUT requests over 64KB.

Kentico routes any requests to [servername]/rest/... through their URLRewritingEngine and rewrites those requests to DocumentRESTService.svc, ObjectTranslationRESTService.svc, or RESTService.svc depending on the type of call. So adding configuration sections to the system.serviceModel doesn't affect the use of those services.

How can we change this limit for the Kentico web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by adding the following pieces of code into the `<system.serviceModel>` section at the end of the web.config file:

Insert a `<webHttpBinding>` element into the `<bindings>` sub-section:

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <!-- Limits set to 10 MB (specified value in bytes) -->

  <binding name="RESTQuotaBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="10485760" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="10485760" />
     <security mode="None" />
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Add a `<service>` element under the `<services>` sub-section:

```
<service name="CMS.WebServices.RESTService">
   <host>
     <baseAddresses>
       <add baseAddress="http://localhost/KenticoCMS/rest" />
     </baseAddresses>
   </host>
   <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="RESTQuotaBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CMS.WebServices.IRESTService" />
</service>
```

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/configuring-the-rest-service#ConfiguringtheRESTservice-Enablinguploadoflargedata

Comment: Thank you for the link, I feel silly for missing that during my search for help. Ultimately, this change did not fix my problem, I'm still receiving the 413 error when a POST or PUT has more than 64KB. In my situation I'm using HTTPS so I needed to change the `<security/>` element to reflect

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because it will work for the services that use CMS.WebServices.RESTService, however, if the services use CMS.DocumentWebServices.DocumentRESTService this answer will not work. Essentially I had to change the service element's 'name' attribute to CMS.DocumentWebServices.DocumentRESTService  and the endpoint element's 'contract' attribute to CMS.DocumentWebServices.IDocumentRESTService and then this solution started working for me.

Comment: @cganickel Were you able to get it working after setting the security mode? I assume you set it to Transport?

Comment: Yes, see my second comment. I just had to change the target of the service, I wonder if you can put all 3 service configurations that use the same endpoint, since they all seem to use /rest as a parent path, but that is a different question.